# How to query the closest item to timestamp in Dynamo DB with Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the AWS Dynamo DB library for Scala - com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.

Earlier I had a table with a primary key and I was using GetItem to get specific item from it like so :

```
val item = Try(Option(ddb.getItem(new GetItemRequest().withTableName(table).withKey(Collections.singletonMap(keyField, new AttributeValue(key)))).getItem).map(_.get(valField).getS))
```

But now I need to start using a new sort key (timestamp of the created date) on top.

This way I can have multiple identical primary keys with different timestamp sort keys.
This is meant so I will be able to get the closest item to my current sort timestamp property.

I think I need `KeyConditionExpression` where my input timestamp is bigger or equal to the new sort key,
and I saw a property `ScanIndexForward` which can be set to true in combination with
limit = 1
so I will get only one item and it will be the closest(?)

And this should get me the desired item I hope, but I am not so sure how to approach this in Scala and with the AWS library.

Comment: To find "closest" you'll have to issue two query requests: one looking for the given time forward (limit 1), one looking for the given time backward (limit 1), and then in the client you'll have to determine which is closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone interested,
this is what worked out for me -

```
val queryRequest = new QueryRequest().withTableName(table)
          .withKeyConditions(createKeyConditionsMap(keyField, keyValue, sortField, sortValue))
          .withScanIndexForward(false)
          .withLimit(1)
val x = ddb.query(queryRequest).getItems()
```

---

```
  def createKeyConditionsMap(keyField: String, keyValue: String, sortField: String, sortValue: String) = {
    Map(keyField -> new Condition().withComparisonOperator("EQ").withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(keyValue)),
    sortField -> new Condition().withComparisonOperator("LE").withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(sortValue))).asJava
  }
```